# Do foreign languages in Windows Server affect the Windows service class?

Tags: windows, vbscript, windows-server-2012-r2

Do foreign languages in Windows Server affect the [Windows service class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-service)?

I have the following VB Script function that checks to see if the windows 
 `netlogon` service is stopped and returns true or false.

My concern is with foreign languages if `.State` is also translated, because if they are translated, then this check would fail because the condition wouldn't evaluate properly because it doesn't say "Stopped".

I've been trying unsuccessfully to get language packs for Windows servers, so I haven't found a way to test or check the foreign languages.

```
Function ISnetlogonServiceStopped()
    netlogonServStoppedCheck = wmi.Get("Win32_Service.Name='" & "netlogon" & "'").State
    If netlogonServStoppedCheck = "Stopped" Then
        ISnetlogonServiceStopped = true
    Else
        ISnetlogonServiceStopped = False
    End IF
End Function
```

Comment: Nearly everything is in English. All programmers have to learn English (or a in case of C a very small subset of English). EG Folders with foreign names are called English names on disk (My Documents) and translated into language specific names in the user interface. PS Japan is the best source of sample code for doing things that it appears no one else has done. One can only read CODE not other text.

Comment: @CatCat if you go to task manager and lo at "Services" tab do it say english "Running" and English "Stopped" or in your own language?

Comment: My language is English so it says *running*. But your code has no relation to the user interface. Code does not change based on language.

Comment: This is what a Japanese programmer sees https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-service and an English programmer sees https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-service. They're identical. Japanese programmers have to type exactly what you typed.

Comment: @CatCat Thanks, I was finally able to add the language pack for another language and run a test code, you are correct, language in UI is irrelevant to the states and properties of code.

Comment: If you look in `%userprofile%\Desktop\Desktop.ini` you'll find this line `LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21770` that will translate `Documents` to the language specific word. Note you are seeing an English translation of Documents (which happens to be the same). However assume it is French. If you type *Mes documents* in a command prompt it won't work, the name is *My Documents*. But you will see *Mes documents* in Explorer.

Comment: What ever is written on MS Web Site is a standard. You can always rely on it. If there are any issues with language or anything else it will be written in the remarks section.

Comment: Also if it did return a localised string (and there are functions that do that) it would be noted as such. You can download the entire Windows API here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

Comment: @CatCat Please summarize this and post it as an answer, so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly everything is in English. All programmers have to learn English (or in case of C a very small subset of English).

This is what a Japanese programmer sees https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-service and an English programmer sees https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-service. They're identical. Japanese programmers have to type exactly what you typed.

---

What ever is written on MS Web Site is a standard. You can always rely on it. If there are any issues with language or anything else it will be written in the remarks section.

The way to view the documentation is as a contract. The contract terms are spelt out in full. What you have to do, and what Windows will do. Often what Windows says it will do is very narrow.

Also if it did return a localised string (and there are functions that do that) it would be noted as such. You can download the entire Windows API here https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

---

EG Folders with foreign names are called English names on disk (My Documents) and translated into language specific names in the user interface.

If you look in `%userprofile%\Desktop\Desktop.ini` you'll find this line `LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21770` that will translate *Documents* to the language specific word. Note you are seeing an English translation of *Documents* (which happens to be the same). However assume it is French. If you type `Mes documents` in a command prompt it won't work, the name is *My Documents*. But you will see *Mes documents* in Explorer.

The file it is accessing is shell32.dll.mui in the EN-US subfolder of System32. If the user has chosen Japanese it will be shell32.dll.mui in the JA-JP subfolder of System32

Comment: An interesting fact. When designing UI for international features you have to allow twice as much space that English takes up because Germans have very long words. But if it's only a one or two word length you may need to make it three or four times larger.